# How do you highlight a tkinter button blue on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, colors

On MacOS, some buttons are highlighted blue (if they signify something important - usually in confirmation dialogs). How do you achieve this in Tkinter, if at all? I am aware that you cannot set the background of a button in Tkinter for MacOS, but I though that there might be a way to "highlight" certain buttons blue.

This is what I mean:

[image: Example of what I mean]

As you can see, one button is coloured blue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you're trying to change the color of the button to show the default action. In this specific case, you can set the `default` option to the string "active" to designate the button as the default button.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x100")

button_frame= tk.Frame(root)

save_button = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Save", default="active")
cancel_button = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Cancel", default="normal")

button_frame.pack(side="bottom", fill="x", padx=8, pady=8)
save_button.pack(side="right")
cancel_button.pack(side="right", padx=8)

root.mainloop()
```

This is designed to use the system colors, but oddly it leaves the foreground as black rather than white.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly. Interestingly, when using this the foreground is set to white for me. Thanks!

Comment: I found that I could change the foreground colour using a custom style: `ttk.Style().configure("active.TButton", foreground="white")` with `ttk.Button(… , style="active.TButton")`. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe tkinter doesn't support colored buttons for MacOS. Here is another package that does add that functionality however, It might be worth it to look at it. https://pypi.org/project/tkmacosx/